# i/o .dat files with Java and how to protect them

Tags: java, io

I plan to write a Java application that works with .dat files - reads from them, updates them, etc. Do you know of any short, basic examples (code)?

I'm also interested in how to somehow protect a .dat file (make it unreadable when opening it). For example, I just converted a notepad file into .dat (by renaming it) - and when I open the .dat I can (obviously) still see the text clearly.

However, I came accross some .dat files that display all sorts of funny characters when opening them - that is protection, right? I've little clue on how to achieve that - I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Well, step #1 would be to identify the exact file format of ".DAT" files and then use *that* when talking about ".DAT" files or searching how to read/modify ".DAT" files. Now, as far as security, there are two basic groups: 1) OS/filesystem security (e.g. file permissions) and; 2) encryption/validation of data at the application level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ".dat" file can be anything you want it to be.

A typical choice is clear-text.

Here is a nice, simple link on reading and writing text files in Java:

- http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0004.html

If you want to "hide" the file, you can set it's file attributes to "hidden".

If you want to prevent people from reading the file, you must encrypt it:

- http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mal503/lore/pkencryption.htm

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the [Basic File IO tutorials.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Writing the files in a binary format isn't done for protection, it just another format which  an be as easily read.

Normally to protect a file you would encrypt it which is fairly complex topic.

If you just want a binary format you can compress the file which will also make it smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful and new things learnt. The question may lack clarity but that's because of my current level of knowledge. I'm satisfied with the answers and think they are an excellent basis for my research.